# How do I loop through Items from one rule without nesting looping the Rule on the next line?

Tags: prolog, predicate

Ive recently started with Prolog and my exact Question is "**Given the name of a room,Print the Items present and the rooms connected to it from the knowledge base**".

My Approach to the question was:

```
room(balcony).
room(bedroom).
room(kitchen).
room(hall).

contains(balcony,shoerack).
contains(balcony,plants).
contains(bedroom,bed).
contains(bedroom,wardrobe).
contains(kitchen,fridge).
contains(kitchen,stove).

contains(hall,sofa).
contains(hall,tv).

door(bedroom,balcony).

door(hall,bedroom).
door(hall,kitchen).

containing(A,B):-room(A),contains(A,B),write('Contains Item:'),write(B),write('\n').
connected(X,Y):-room(X),room(Y),door(X,Y),write('Connected to:'),write(Y),write('\n').

input(P):-write('Enter Place:'),read(P).
start:-
    input(P),
    connected(P,_),
    containing(P,_),
    fail.
start.
```

The issue I'm facing is

[image: OUTPUT]

It's treating the second rule as a nested rule and looping through its items then returns control back to the Top-most rule and reiterating the items again.

I want it to loop through and print all the adjacent rooms First then print all the Items.

Comment: please don't post pictures of text; simply copy and paste the text, just as you did for your source code!

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result, you could use two *independent* failure-driven loops:

```
items(A) :-
    room(A),
    contains(A, B),
    write('Contains item: '),
    write(B),
    write('\n'),
    fail.
items(_).

connections(X) :-
    room(X),
    room(Y),
    door(X,Y),
    write('Connected to: '),
    write(Y),
    write('\n'),
    fail.
connections(_).

start :-
    input(X),
    items(X),
    connections(X).
```

Example:

```
?- start.
Enter Place: hall.
Contains item: sofa
Contains item: tv
Connected to: bedroom
Connected to: kitchen
true.
```

**Remark** Try using the predicate [`forall/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2) instead of classical failure-driven loops.